Why is M-x ivy-switch-buffer in Emacslient blocking Emacs?
If I open Emacsclient and then M-x ivy-switch-buffer, then Emacs is frozen and there's no way to unblock it, except finishing up ivy-switch-buffer in Emacsclient.
Is this a limitation or a bug?
I mean, if I log in via ssh and I'm working, then suddenly interrupted by a phone call of whatever, which causes me to leave; then my Emacs is unrecoverable if I log in from ssh from somewhere else.
I would always need to leave in a valid state, so to speak.
I just want to confirm if this is a limitation or a bug, first of all.

It's not just ivy-switch-buffer: any function that asks for input is going to block waiting for the input to arrive (try read-string). While the function is waiting, so is the server which is waiting for the lisp expression that was passed from emacsclient to be evaluated - it has to send back the return value of the expression back to emacsclient, so it's going to wait until the function is finished. While it's waiting, the server is "busy" waiting, so any other emacsclient will get a busy signal (after a while it will time out). You'll have to clean up before you get up and leave.
